# Binding (WPF MVVM) SciChart zooming property to a button

Tags: wpf, scichart

I am using the WPF SciChart tool. i want to bind the zoom functionality to a button. for zoom-in and zoom-out. i read all the help and tutorials. they have zoom history binding options. but the zoom itself is bound to mouse button scroll. Added the code. there are ways to do in in the mouse and click events on the chart. but nothing outside.

```
<s:SciChartSurface s:ThemeManager.Theme="BrightSpark" Name="ChartSurface" 
                       RenderableSeries="{s:SeriesBinding SeriesViewModels}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
            <s:NumericAxis AxisTitle="Estimated Time [hh:mm:ss]"/>
        </s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>

        <s:SciChartSurface.YAxis>
            <s:NumericAxis  GrowBy="0.1, 0.1" AxisAlignment="Left"  AxisTitle="Temperature [°C]"/>
        </s:SciChartSurface.YAxis>
        <s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>
            <s:ModifierGroup>
                <!-- Allow drag to zoom on Left mouse -->
                <s:RubberBandXyZoomModifier ExecuteOn="MouseLeftButton" 
                                            RubberBandFill="#33FFFFFF" RubberBandStroke="#AAFFFFFF"
                                            RubberBandStrokeDashArray="2 2" IsXAxisOnly="True" />
                <s:MouseWheelZoomModifier ActionType="Zoom" XyDirection="XDirection"/>
                <!-- Allow pan on Right mouse drag -->
                <s:ZoomPanModifier ExecuteOn="MouseRightButton" ClipModeX="None" />
                <!-- Allow Dragging YAxis to Scale -->
                <s:YAxisDragModifier DragMode="Scale"/>
                <!-- Allow Dragging XAxis to Pan -->
                <s:XAxisDragModifier DragMode="Pan"/>
                <!-- Allow Mousewheel Zoom -->
                <s:MouseWheelZoomModifier/>
                <!-- Allow Zoom to Extents on double click -->
                <s:ZoomExtentsModifier ExecuteOn="MouseDoubleClick" />
            </s:ModifierGroup>
        </s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>
        </s:SciChartSurface>
```

Comment: Can you show the code which have tried?